# video is not playing with aspect ratio of device in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I have used surface view to play video from server. I have used Async task to play view.And shown a progress dialog till the video is prepared to play in media player. doinbackground code is as follows.

```
 holder = mpreview.getHolder();
 holder.addCallback(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this);
 holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Every thing is perfect but problem is video not playing in proper size, means very small in big resolution device.How to set size of surface view as it is defined in Oncreate() and rest code is given from Async task.

Comment: please add your code of surface holder and the method where you define dimensions of the surfaceView

Comment: this is code of onsurfaceCreated method mMediaplayer= new MediaPlayer();mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);       mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); and crated a surfaceview object in oncrate

Comment: Is the video mad in portrait mode and played in landscape mode or vice versa?

Comment: In both mode i am playing the video or activity

Comment: Does it stretch in both cases or which of them. Your problem occurs when surface view and video follows two different aspect ratios. i.e video shot in landscape mode and played in portrait mode makes it go stretchy and awkward.